# NHibernate - Select query in Formula attribute of Property element is not working

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am new to NHibernate.
I am using following property elements in my hbm file...

```
<property name="CountryId" length="4" />
<property name="CountryForCustomer"
              formula="(SELECT *
                            FROM SystemCountry  
                            WHERE SystemCountry.CountryId = CountryId)" />
```

Here I am trying to get Country details from the CountryId that I am having in an other table.

Property "CountryForCustomer" is of custom type "SystemCountry".

But this query in formula is not working.. So someone please help me solving this issue.

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should it not be

```
SELECT SystemCountry.Country FROM SystemCountry WHERE...
```

as the `*` would return multiple columns from the query

**edit** If you want to return the whole object back then the `property` element is not your friend here. What you want to do is look at the many-to-one element, note that this is just one way to do this.

```
<many-to-one name="CmsTemplate" column="TemplateId" ..
```

e.g. [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/09/nhibernate-mapping-ltmany-to-onegt.aspx) or [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)

Comment: ok, got your point.. But I want whole object of Country to use and not only one column value.. so how to achive that using hbm file mapping..?

Comment: Now this solution is working but there is an issue.... When I initially inserting data or updating the data(using SaveorUpdate method of NHibernate), it do not bring the associated data with "many-to-one" element as I have set the "insert" and "update" attributes to false as keeping them true gives the error -> IndexOutOfRangeException -> "Invalid index 52 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=52." So how to move forward from here..?

Comment: This is an entirely different question. Add a `new` question providing your mapping and poco classes. Then we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

the Formula mapping does not map its value from the database ,it maps its value from the dataset which is loaded in the session